# Data Structure for A* Algorithm

Tags: c#, data-structures, a-star, sortedlist, sortedset

Going off of this link:[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

Which data structure would be the best for keeping track of Heuristic, Movement Cost, and the sum of the two for a given Bitmap? The two main ones I've been thinking about were SortedSet and SortedList. Other sources say to use a priority queue, but as far as I know, C# doesn't have one.

So things to keep track of would be:

- The x and y coordinate of a pixel.
- The Movement Cost (no diagonals)
- The Hueristics (using Manhattan distance)
- The sum of the two
- Parent of the Node

I'm planning to create a node object that will have the following:

- Tuple (xcoordinate, ycoordinate)
- Parent node

What data structure should I use and how should i organize my node to best fit my needs?

Comment: I would implement my own heap in C# and use it in A* as it is the best fit here.

Comment: You should read these articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/astar/

Answer (score 0):

Use a priority queue to hold the developed nodes, which compare (d + h) of each node to sort them in the priority queue. "d" is the current depth of the node, and "h" is the calculated heuristic value of the node or the estimated future steps.